# Rendering curly braces multiple times in Bash

Tags: bash, templates, variables, import, export

I like to interpret curly braces twice or completely, like a templating system in a bash script.

I have a script like this:

envfile:

```sh
ROOT=/var/log
APP_LOG=${ROOT}/app
```

bash:

```sh
# importing the vars from script
export $(grep -v '^#' .envfile | xargs -d '\n')

echo ${ROOT}
echo ${APP_LOG}
```

prints:

```sh
/var/log
${ROOT}/app
```

but I'd like to have `/var/log/app` from `${APP_LOG}`, without to glue it with `ROOT`.

Comment: Use the `source` or `dot` command. `source .envfile` then `printf '%s\n' "$ROOT" "$APP_LOG"` inside the script.

Comment: I have edited your post a little, but I'm not sure what you mean with "glu" in the last sentence.

Comment: @BenjaminW., looks like google translate failed  for the OP :-)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jetchisel wrote I use source

```
set -a
. .envfile
```

(the dot is another notation for source)
works much better!

Thanks